Modern term for "armed" magnets
In De Magnete William Gilbert (see here) talks about armed lodestone in Chapter 17. It is a technique where the lifting force of a magnet (by contact) is increased manifold by 'simply' adding to one of its poles a cap of good quality steel for example.
Similar reports can be found about some works from Galileo here and later on Le Monnier reports here (in French) on 'l'armure de l'aimant'.
The phenomenology being described is always the same:

The technique amplifies greatly the lifting power of the armed magnet
It however does not affect the ability of the armed magnet to magnetise other objects. It remains similar in activity to that of the bare magnet.
In fact, as reported by Gilbert, putting a simple sheet of paper between the armed magnet and the iron to be lifted is sufficient to completely annihilate the multiplicative effect.

Trying to find information about this effect in modern search engines appears quite difficult because they either return historical accounts (which is fine of course) or simply return pictures of kitchen magnets related to military themes (guns, rifles, aircrafts etc...).
It is likely that 'armed magnets' are not called like this anymore. Would anyone know if there is a 'modern' term for it?
Of course, I am conscious that nowadays the technique may appear obsolete because it is essentially replaced by electromagnets, but the effect should remain of some interest to physicists I think (at least great interest to me).

Fo what it's worth (https://crane1.com/restoring-magnetic-strength-tip-reinforcing-weak-magnet/):

For certain applications, adding a backing material to a weak magnet
can significantly help with restoring magnetic strength and improving
its magnetic strength. By sandwiching the magnet between two metal
plates, such as iron or steel, the magnetic flux lines are
concentrated and reinforced. This technique, known as magnetic
backing, increases the magnet’s magnetic field, resulting in enhanced
performance. Ensure the backing material is in direct contact with the
magnet’s surface for maximum effect.

